# pythonでxmlファイルの一部分の情報を抽出したい

Tags: python, python3, xml

#### 実現したいこと

`result.xml`という名のxmlファイルの **`<passage>`** の中のabstractの **`<text>`** の抽出をしたい.
**`<text>`** の部分は, `Neurologic complications of COVID-19, ~ encephalopathy.` の文と `The rapid evolution~replication.` の文を抽出したい.

ファイル: result.xml

```xml
<collection>
  <document>
    <passage>
      <infon key="authors">Gupta NA, Lien C, Iv M, </infon>
      <offset>0</offset>
      <text>Critical illness-associated cerebral microbleeds in severe COVID-19 infection </text>
      <annotation id="5">
        <location offset="68" length="9" />
        <text>infection</text>
      </annotation>
    </passage>
    <passage>
      <infon key="section_type">ABSTRACT</infon>
      <infon key="type">abstract</infon>
      <offset>81</offset>
      <text>Neurologic complications of COVID-19 infection have been recently described and include dizziness, headache, loss of taste and smell, stroke, and encephalopathy.</text>
    </passage>
    <passage>
      <infon key="section_type">ABSTRACT</infon>
      <infon key="type">abstract_title_1</infon>
      <offset>584</offset>
      <text>Highlights</text>
    </passage>
  </document>
  <document>
    <passage>
      <infon key="name_4">surname:Ansari;given-names:M. Azim</infon>
      <offset>0</offset>
      <text>Extensive C->U transition biases in the genomes of a wide range of mammalian RNA viruses; potential associations with transcriptional mutations, damage- or host-mediated editing of viral RNA</text>
      <annotation id="1">
        <infon key="identifier">9606</infon>
        <infon key="type">Species</infon>
        <location offset="67" length="9" />
        <text>mammalian</text>
      </annotation>
    </passage>
    <passage>
      <infon key="type">abstract</infon>
      <offset>191</offset>
      <text>The rapid evolution of RNA viruses SARS-CoV-2 has been long considered to result from a combination of high copying error frequencies during RNA replication. </text>
    </passage>
    <passage>
      <infon key="section_type">ABSTRACT</infon>
      <infon key="type">abstract_title_1</infon>
      <offset>2033</offset>
      <text>Author summary</text>
    </passage>
  </document>
</collection>
```

スクリプト: 1.py

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('result.xml') as xml:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

result = []

for passage in soup.find_all('passage'):
    text = passage.text
    if text and ('COVID-19' in text or 'SARS-CoV-2' in text):
        for line in text.splitlines():
            if line.strip().endswith('.'):
                result3.append(line)

print(*result,sep='^\n')
```

Comment: printの箇所が構文エラーが出てしまうのですがどうすればよいでしょうか.

Comment: print(result)で出力を見て頂けますでしょうか

Comment: [u'Neurologic complications of COVID-19 infection have been recently described and include dizziness, headache, loss of taste and smell, stroke, and encephalopathy.', u'The rapid evolution of RNA viruses  SARS-CoV-2 has been long considered to result from a combination of high copying error frequencies during RNA replication.']このようにでました.

Comment: Python**2** ってことはありませんか？ `python -V` (大文字 V) でバージョン出ます

Comment: python 2.7.17でした.

Comment: 何系の OSかわからないけど, 何にしても Python3に移行したほうがよいと思います。Linuxとかだと `python3` で Python3 起動可能

Comment: 解決できました.ありがとうございました.

Comment: 解決の場合は プラス投票とか回答の承認とかできます [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: あー, プラス投票はもしかするとスコア足りないかも

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoupを利用します．

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

result = []

for passage in soup.find_all('passage'):
    text = passage.text
    if text and ('COVID-19' in text or 'SARS-CoV-2' in text):
        for line in text.splitlines():
            if line.strip().endswith('.'):
                result.append(line)

print(*result, sep='\n')

# Neurologic complications of COVID-19 infection have been recently described and include dizziness, headache, loss of taste and smell, stroke, and encephalopathy.
# The rapid evolution of RNA viruses SARS-CoV-2 has been long considered to result from a combination of high copying error frequencies during RNA replication.
```

#### 補足

- 行末がピリオドで終わるものを文としました(その際前後の空白を除去しています)．
- (追記)`if text and (...`について，textがNoneの場合(passageにtextタグが含まれていなかった場合)に次の`test in ...`でエラーを吐くことを防ぐ目的で，短絡評価を利用しています．

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup で CSS セレクタを使う場合。

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('result.xml') as xml:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

texts = soup.select('''
  passage >
  infon[key="type"]:-soup-contains("abstract"):not(:-soup-contains("_title")) ~
  text:-soup-contains("COVID-19", "SARS-CoV-2")
''')
text = [t.text for t in texts]

print('\n'.join(text))

#
Neurologic complications of COVID-19 infection have been recently described and include dizziness, headache, loss of taste and smell, stroke, and encephalopathy.
The rapid evolution of RNA viruses SARS-CoV-2 has been long considered to result from a combination of high copying error frequencies during RNA replication.
```

Comment: 少し質問なんですけど、xmlのファイルにdocumentの中に<passage><infon key="section_type">ABSTRACT</infon><infon key="type">abstract</infon><offset>655</offset><text>Critical illness-associated cerebral microbleeds can be seen in the setting of severe COVID-19.</text>追加されてたりすると,単語検索だとこの文章も取り出してしまうのですが，Neurologic~encephalopathy.の文章のみを抽出したいと考えているのですが，単語検索では難しいと思うのですが，どういった考え方で取り出すべきでしょうか.

Comment: 現時点は削除された様ですけど、「検索条件としては、<text> の文にCOVID-19かSARS-CoV-2のどちらかの単語が含まれています」との条件に従って書いたものです。やるとすれば、"Neurologic" と "encephalopathy" の両方を含む、という条件に変更することになります。